# jQuery: On form select focus, show div. hide div on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

sorry for my english

I have this code :

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mickeymic/gZSgW/2/)

no problem

How I can adapt the code when "select" is like this :

```
<select id="example[164]" name="example[164]" type="text" />
<option value="0">0</option>    
<option value="1">1</option>    
<option value="2">2</option>    
<option value="3">3</option>    
</select>
<div class="test">    
Some text...<br /><input type="checkbox" name="foobar" value="1" /><br />More text...       
</div>`
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mickeymic/AVjFK/2/)

Thanks for your help

:D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This HTML is not valid except in HTML5.  The characters `[]` are not permitted in the `id` attribute, which should be letters, numbers, periods, hyphens, underscores, and colons.

To match that invalid id with jQuery, you would need to escape the `[]` with *two* backslashes:

```
// Match all select elements beginning with example in the id
$('#example\\[164\\]')
```

In context of your example, change `$('#example')` to `$('#example\\[164\\]')`

```
$('#example\\[164\\]').focus(function() {
    if (timer)
        clearTimeout(timer);
    $('div.test').css('display','block');
    // etc...
```

Later, it also appears as:
function(e) {

```
    if ($(e.target).closest('.example, #example\\[164\\]').length) return;
```

However, since this is *not* a valid id attribute (unless you are using HTML5), you should instead match on the element's `name` attribute, and if this is being generated on the server side, instead change the id attribute to something valid like `<select id='example_164'>`.

```
// [] are valid in a name
$('select[name="example[164]"').focus(function() {
    if (timer)
        clearTimeout(timer);
    $('div.test').css('display','block');
```

[Here is the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mickeymic/AVjFK/2/)

Comment: You can quote the attribute value in the attribute selector to avoid having to escape the braces by the way.